# How to get my third thumb button work under gnome-shell? How to find out what is stealing the button event, or how to get around it?

Tags: mouse, gnome-shell

Arch linux. Gnome-shell. Logitech M705.

I would like to use my m705 logitech mouses extra thumb button in gnome shell. I was used it w/o any problem in elementary os.
But now I can't because it is not seen by system. (Or .. very rarely ....)
Xev gimes me this:

```
---
LeaveNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x1fd, subw 0x0, time 26598769, (163,154), root:(228,281),
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

FocusOut event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  4294967293 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

EnterNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x1fd, subw 0x0, time 26598917, (163,154), root:(228,281),
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 0

KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

---
```

It was between two mouse button 1 event to make sure I get everything.
I was thought that with showkeys / setkeycodes I could remap that button but showkeys doesn't show mouse buttons.

But rarely it is going through. So sometimes that thing what is "stealing" that event from me (howdareshe...) isn't working 100%. But I don't think that matters now.

I hope I was understandable. Yoroshiku.